# Создание backend

Tags: java, android, httpbackend

Здравствуйте.

Прочитал много информации по данной теме, но ничего из этого меня не устроило.
Занимаюсь этим в первый раз, так что не ругайтесь)

Написал проект на java - стоит задача перенести его в андроид приложение. Можно запихнуть его целиком, но было бы интереснее создать сервер, к которому бы это приложение обращалось. Все, что сейчас требуется, это передать картинку и немножко текста серверу и получить от него немножко другого текста, например, в формате Json.

Однако, я вижу какой-то темный лес с контроллерами, графической частью и т.д. Есть ли какое-то простое решение?

Comment: С чем проблема: с созданием бекенда или приложения?

Comment: Проблема с созданием бэкенда

Comment: т.е. нужно переделать уже существующий проект в сервер.

Comment: @Валентин это цель. а проблема в том, что не знаешь с чего начать?

Comment: Совершенно верно

Comment: Хотите сделать что то быстрее и проще то посмотрите в сторону спринг бута, вот туториал в котором создаётся примитивный(но рабочий) rest https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, нужно понять, каким образом происходит взаимодействие с бэкендом. По большому счёту, выбора два: http и WebSocket. Из Вашего описания ясно, что рассматривается http: он предполагает клиент-серверное взаимодействие. То есть, сервер по определённому адресу (URL) слушает (на определённом TCP-порту), когда клиент запросит у него соединение. Таким образом, взаимодействие начинается по инициативе клиента. О протоколе HTTP в интернете очень много информации, включая [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) (правда, уже несколько устаревшую, но не утратившую актуальности).

Протокол http 1.1, который в настоящее время в основном используется для такого взаимодействия, текстовый. То есть, после установления соединения клиент начинает слать серверу запрос, состоящий из потока символов. Сервер как-то обрабатывает этот поток символов и возвращает клиенту поток символов в ответ. На этом всё, цикл "запрос"-"ответ" закончен.
Значит, Вам нужны две библиотеки - http-сервер, умеющий слушать указанный TCP-порт и предоставлять в Ваше распоряжение текстовый поток запроса и возможность записать ответный поток. Многие серверные http-библиотеки также предоставляют удобные инструменты для анализа и разбора url-строки, http-заголовков и т.д. В простейшем случае для Java это, например, [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html). 
И http-клиент в Андроиде, который будет отправлять серверу http-запросы и получать ответы.

Собственно, JSON, который сервер должен прислать в ответ - это тоже поток символов. Но его нужно каким-то образом сформировать из тех структур данных, которые есть в доступном Вам языке программирования. В простейшем случае можно воспользоваться конкатенацией строк и значений переменных. В более сложных случаях, а также для удобства и уменьшения ошибок, используют специальные библиотеки, которые помогают выполнять преобразования из текстового JSON или XML в структуры данных языка и обратно. Значит, нужно определиться со способом этого преобразования.

Наконец, нужно где-то Ваш сервер развернуть. Удобно для этого воспользоваться, например, [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

А можно в качестве бэкенда вообще взять готовое JSON-хранилище вроде [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

Для отлаживания бэкенда на локальном компьютере очень удобно использовать http-клиенты вроде [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).
Если есть более конкретные вопросы - задавайте.

Если есть желание начать делать что-то сложное и интересное - очень рекомендую познакомиться с [Elixir-ом](http://elixir-lang.org/) и [Phoenix-ом](http://www.phoenixframework.org/) на виртуальной машине Erlang.

С ростом опыта придёт понимание, что у серверной логики достаточно много задач, и в одной куче с ними разбираться неудобно. Окажется, что лучше всего отделить логику взаимодействия с внешними устройствами и протоколами (база данных, сеть, диск, очередь) и ядро, реализующее ключевую бизнес-логику системы. Тогда придёт время знакомиться с Гексагональной Архитектурой. Потом окажется, что всё это должно обрабатывать десятки или сотни запросов от разных пользователей одновременно - тогда можно будет освоить Модель Акторов. Или другую из реализованных абстракций параллельного и конкурентного программирования.

Но, конечно, чтобы написать свой первый http-бэкенд это всё не является необходимым.